# Add items to columns in QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I am currently adding rows to my `QTableView` as such

```
QStandardItem* itm;
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
model->setColumnCount(2);
model->appendRow(new QStandardItem("Some Text in Column1");
```

How do I add items to column 2 dynamically by appending?
In the above example column 2 is empty. How do I add item to column 2?

Answer (score 10):

Calling appendRow(QStandardItem *) only adds a single item to the first column.  You would need to pass in a QList to appendRow() to add items to each column, e.g.:

```
QList<QStandardItem *> items;

items.append(new QStandardItem("Column 1 Text"));
items.append(new QStandardItem("Column 2 Text"));

QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(this);

model->setColumnCount(2);
model->appendRow(items);
```

See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#appendRow for more detail.